# Irreducible in rings understanding

Tags: ring-theory

Problem: Let $a$ be an irreducible element of a principal ideal domain $\mathbb{R}$. If
$b\in\mathbb{R}$  and $a$ does not divide $b$, show that $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime
My attempt: let $\text{gcd}(a, b) = d$, then $d|a$ and $d|b$

$d|a \rightarrow a = d * m$ where either $d$ or $m$ is unit.

$d|b \rightarrow b = d* n$ where either $d$ or $n$ is unit

but I don't know how to argue to get $\text{gcd}(a, b) = 1$
Please, explain me.

Answer (score 2):

Now that you've proven $a = dm$ with either $d$ or $m$ being unit, if $m$ is unit, then $am^{-1} = d$ and thus $a\mid d$, and consequently $a\mid b$, which contradicts your hypothesis, so $m$ cannot be a unit and $d$ must be a unit, which means $\text{gcd}(a, b) = 1$.

Comment: My question is right there. If d is unit , why gcd(a,b) =1? By definition, d is a unit in R, then d has inverse. It didn't say that unit is 1. How to convert d to 1?

Comment: @user73195 $\gcd$ is unique only up to a unit. Since units are invertible,  $c\mid a$ and $c\mid b$ iff $cu\mid a$ and $cu\mid b$ for any unit $u$.

Comment: @user73195 By the way, this property holds for all UFDs, not only for PIDs.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ a\nmid b\,\Rightarrow (c) = (a,b)\supsetneq (a)\,$ so $\,c\mid a\,$ *properly* so $\,c\,$ is a unit, by $\,a\,$ irreducible. Therefore $\,(1) = (c) =(a,b)\,$ so $\,r a + s b = 1$ so $\,d\mid a,b\,\Rightarrow\, d\mid 1 = ra+sb,\,$ so $\,a,b\,$ are coprime.